# Is Using CDN Libraries in App Exchange allowed?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, appexchange

We are in process of publishing our App in App Exchange. 
I am using the following library in my visual force page

```
<apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" / >
        <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
```

Is it allowed? Will using the following create any problem while publishing in App Exchange?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not allowed. See the [Requirements Checklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Requirements_Checklist):

> - All script and style resources must be loaded via static resources. Do not load resources dynamically with a link or script tag. Do not hotlink to javascript code outside of static resources.
> - To aid in reviewing custom javascript, include un-minified source files when submitting for the security review corresponding to all minified files in static resources. Please give the unminified files the same name (except .min), for scanning purposes. Do not combine unminified and minified files together. Also include source files for all languages that transpile to javascript in your code (e.g. JSX). Auxiliary source files should be provided in static resources.

If you link to a CDN, you will fail your review. Use static resources, and set Caching to Public so that any intermediate proxies can cache the resources.